# No Burglars Allowed

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*Thief! Thief! He took my rock!*

[image: bandits_1] [image: bandits_2] [image: bandits_3] [image: bandits_4]

[image: bandits_5] [image: bandits_6] [image: bandits_7]

<sup><sup>*(Click individual images to enlarge)*</sup></sup>

Answer is a **thematic word.**

---

Text transcript of the posters (for copy/paste purposes)

```
Brooks Bryce, 24
143 counts of petty theft
Last known location: BOS
REWARD: $13,660,716

Cam Barlow, 31
98 counts of petty theft
Last known location: UTA
REWARD: $27,045,455

Robin Fernandez, 27
80 counts of petty theft
Last known location: MIL
REWARD: $22,000,000

Tony Ferguson, 26
71 counts of petty theft
Last known location: ORL
REWARD: $37,000,000

Clarence Hayes, 30
123 counts of petty theft
Last known location: IND
REWARD: $14,764,045

Russ Lowe, 23
64 counts of petty theft
Last known location: LAL
REWARD: $20,655,160

George Raymond, 28
88 counts of petty theft
Last known location: POR
REWARD: $31,977,689
```

Comment: Helpful information for solvers: rot13(Gur 7 crbcyr cvpgherq ner AON cynlref: Znephf Fzneg, Wbr Vatyrf, Xuevf Zvqqyrgba, Rina Sbheavre, Gunqqrhf Lbhat, Wbfu Uneg, Qnzvna Yvyyneq.  Gur pbhagf bs crggl gursg ner gurve fgrny gbgnyf va gur 2018-2019 frnfba, naq V oryvrir gurve ntrf ner pbeerpg sbe gung frnfba nf jryy, nybat jvgu gurve grnz pvgl.  Gur erjneq nzbhagf ner abg gurve fnynevrf, fb gung vf fgvyy na haxabja.)

Comment: @JS1 - another related (and possibly coincidental) observation: rot13(gur anzrf lbh yvfg unir gur fnzr yrggre pbhagf nf gurve chmmyr nyvnfrf, jvgu rknpgyl bar pbeerfcbaqvat yrggre cre crefba: F Y V S N F Q)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thematic word is:

> **BANDITS**

Because:

> The portraits are of NBA players whose:
>
>  1. Names are the same lengths as the fake names
>  2. Teams in 2018-2019 were the same city as the last known location
>  3. Steals in 2018-2019 were the same number as the petty theft counts
>  4. Ages in 2018-2019 matched the ages listed
>  5. Have one letter in common between the fake name and the real name. (From Alconja)
>
>  They are: Marcus Smart, Joe Ingles, Khris Middleton, Evan Fournier, Thaddeus Young, Josh Hart, and Damian Lillard.
>
>  Now, if you look up the salaries of these players from the 2018-2019 season, and compare to the rewards offered, the rewards are even multiples of million dollars higher than the salaries, by these amounts (in millions):
>
>  2, 14, 9, 20, 1, 19, 4
>
>  Which correspond to the letters: BNITASD.  If you arrange these letters from the person with the highest petty theft count to the least (the order being 1527346), the letters spell out "BANDITS".
>
>   Other clue I missed: If you take the letters in common between the fake names and the real names: SLIFASD, and arrange them the same way as the before, you get SALDIFS, which points to the salary differences being significant.
>
>  By the way, the site I used to look up all the stats and salaries was [basketball-reference.com](https://www.basketball-reference.com/).

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I fixed up the answer after figuring out what yoh meant.

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Oh, I finally figured out what that word meant!

Comment: All good now, congrats!